# Error "org.eclipse.jface" with MySQL in Eclipse Neon (MAC)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, macos, javafx

Create a remote database with mysql (on a pc with windows) which I raised with neon eclipse (javafx project) on a mac. I raise correctly I can even edit the tables and so on, but always when I connect it it throws me error Argument not valid. In errorlog figure:

> Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4514)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:631)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor._createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createResource(ImageDescriptor.java:164)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.DeviceResourceManager.allocate(DeviceResourceManager.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.AbstractResourceManager.create(AbstractResourceManager.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ResourceManager.createImageWithDefault(ResourceManager.java:192)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageRegistry.get(ImageRegistry.java:204)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.ProfileImageRegistry.getProfileImage(ProfileImageRegistry.java:37)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.navigator.ConnectionProfileLabelProvider.getImage(ConnectionProfileLabelProvider.java:71)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.findImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:199)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getColumnImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:107)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:99)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider$StyledLabelProviderAdapter.getImage(NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider.java:57)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:195)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:121)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:949)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:118)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1029)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:474)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2170)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.internalUpdate(StructuredViewer.java:2153)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.update(StructuredViewer.java:2094)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.update(ColumnViewer.java:542)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.update(CommonViewer.java:512)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.update(StructuredViewer.java:2038)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleLabelProviderChanged(StructuredViewer.java:1209)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleLabelProviderChanged(CommonViewer.java:237)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer$1.labelProviderChanged(ContentViewer.java:99)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.BaseLabelProvider$1.run(BaseLabelProvider.java:72)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.BaseLabelProvider.fireLabelProviderChanged(BaseLabelProvider.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.lambda$0(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:75)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratorManager$1.run(DecoratorManager.java:374)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratorManager.fireListener(DecoratorManager.java:371)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$3.runInUIThread(DecorationScheduler.java:511)
at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:97)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4032)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3708)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

What could be failing? Try to remove the .classpath and .proyect and reload the project but continue the problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue..
Took me three hours to figure out what the heck it was for me.

Had installed a eclipse plugin called "Darkest dark theme" which somehow screws up your icon loader. 
The fault is that the icon that should be displayed on the line cannot be loaded for the database connection.
Just uninstalled darkest Dark theme and int works just fine.

Comment: thank you very much! I'm going to try this solution, I had that theme and also uninstall it, maybe I did not do it right.